# Undefined type 'App\\Models\\import' laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, import, export

i tried use this code

make class in imports

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\import;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class RtdImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new import([
            'status' => $row['status'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

but i have problem notes like this:

```
Undefined type 'App\\Models\\import'
```

how to solve it

this for import data sql to excel use maat excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely your autoloading that is off. Firstly classes start with capital letters.

Your import class file should be located here.

```
app/Models/Import.php
```

The definition of the class should be with the namespace.

```
namespace App\Models;

class Import {
}
```

You should use it like this, off course add your own parameters to the import etc.

```
use App\Models\Import;

new import([]);
```